# Using Solr Geohash

Tags: solr, geospatial

I would like to pass use the geohash field type available in solr, but there is minimal documentation for it.  System documentation makes it seem like it may be pending the 4.0 release, but the schema document references it.

Does anyone know if it's available in 3.3?

If it is, can the lat long pair be just passed in, or does the hash need to be precompiled?

if it needs to be precomplied what format does it expect the hash to be in (binary, hex etc) in order to the distance parameter in spatial searches to work?

Answer (score 1):

The hash will have to be precompiled. I would recommend using the location type instead of the geohash. Since you seem to already have the latitude and longitude at hand you can simply import both values into one field:

```
<field name="Your_coordinates" type="location">31.123,-84.123</field>
```

where 31.123 is latitude and -84.123 is longitude